# rake db:load doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake-task

I'm totaly noob in Ruby, and I can't execute the command `rake db:load`. Sorry for stupid question, but I need help.
The same error is thrown on `rake db:seed`

```
root@root:/var/www/dir# rake db:load --trace
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23
```

Comment: Are you actually running this from a Rails project?

Comment: Maybe `cd` into the folder of your Rails app?

Comment: I in folder with Rails app. I runing https://github.com/jamesu/tubehub this.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues with this project. First of all it lacks a Javascript runtime. You can solve this by adding

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

to the GemFile and rerunning

```
bundle install
```

The second problem is that there is no db:load task specified. Looking at the code you want to use

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

That should work.

Comment: root@root:/var/www/synch# bundle exec rake db:schema:load
rake aborted!
/var/www/synch/util.rb:8: undefined (?...) sequence: /^(.*?)((?<!&)#|\#)(.*)$/
/var/www/synch/util.rb:9: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?:\#)(?<!&#)(?:\#)*(.*)$/
/var/www/synch/core.rb:37
/var/www/synch/core.rb:36:in `each'
/var/www/synch/core.rb:36
/var/www/synch/Rakefile:2:in `require'
/var/www/synch/Rakefile:2
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: you need to navigate into the /tubehub folder and run that command. You currently seem to be running it from /var/www/synch.

Comment: I'm actually in `/var/www/tabehub/`, just renamed dir.